# PostgreSQL - DDL Statement Function parameter

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Is it possible to pass DDL statements as function parameters?

Something like this:

```
select MyAlterTable('Employees', add column CA name(250));
select MyAlterTable('Customers', add column CA name(250));
```

final statement would be:

```
alter table Employees
    add column CA name(250)
```

Or should I pass them as string and use `execute` command?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass that as a string and use dynamic SQL.

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name your help is much appreciated!